# Binding data between $ionicPlatform.ready() & a controller in AngularJS Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, binding, push-notification

I used the Push Plugin in the app.ready() like this 
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

```
window.onNotification = function(e) {
    switch( e.event ) {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 ) {
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.

                window.localStorage.setItem('regid',e.regid);
            }
            break;
        case 'message':
            if (e.foreground) {
                //HI, HERE I GET THE NOTIFICATION MESSAGE e.payload.message
            }
    }
}
```

I have a controller which shows the messages in the html :

```
.controller("msjctrl", function() {
    this.msjs=['message1','message2'];
}
```

and the html

```
<ion-content id="msjcontent" ng-controller="msjctrl as mm">
    <h1 class="button-positive" id="log">Mensajes</h1>
    <div class='card' ng-repeat="msj in mm.msjs">
        {{msj}}
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

How can i push the obtained message from app.ready() in the controller's msjs array (binding way) ?

Comment: What is `app.ready()`? Is it Angular module's `run`, or is it Cordova's `deviceready`, or just the DOM `ready`?

Comment: Hi Corey, im using Ionic Framework.  The  .ready() function is from module's run. 



.run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$rootScope) {

 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `app.ready()` method has access to Angular's `$rootScope`, perhaps you could broadcast the change. This is untested, but something like this:

```
// inside the `message` case statement
if (e.foreground) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('$newMessageReceived', e.payload.message);
}
```

Then, watch for the broadcast in your controller:

```
.controller('msjctrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    this.msjs=['message1','message2'];

    $scope.$on('$newMessageReceived', function(e, msg) {
        console.log('message received:', msg);
        self.msjs.push(msg);
    });
})
```

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5tqw5wmb/).

Comment: Thanks Corey. I changed this.msjs to $scope.msjs and the msj was pushed. The problem is the view isnt updating. i tried with $scope.apply() but it didnt work.

Comment: Do you see the message in the console log? Also, I added a 'self' variable to handle the function scope issue. Check out the jsfiddle at the bottom as a simple demo.

Comment: Yes, the message shows correctly. After pushing, i did an alert(self.msjs[2]); to watch the new msj and is correct. However, the view isnt updating. Ionic bugs maybe?

Comment: I dont know why view wast updating. I ve solved reloading the $state of Ionic " $state.reload() " . I think it inst the correclty way but it works...

Comment: Maybe try wrapping it in a $timeout? `$timeout(function() { self.msjs.push(msg); });`